# Re-adjusting (automatically) limits on plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bounds

Is there a way to let matplotlib know to recompute the optimal bounds of a plot?

My problem is that, I am manually computing a bunch of boxplots, putting them at various locations in a plot. By the end, some boxplots extend beyond the plot frame. I could hard-code some xlim and ylim's for now, but I want a more general solution.

What I was thinking was a feature where you say "ok plt I am done plotting, now please adjust the bounds so that all my data is nicely within the bounds".

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
The answer is yes.

**Follow-up question:** Can this be done for the ticks as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use matplotlib's automatic axis scaling. You can do this with either [`axes.axis`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axis) with the "auto" input or [`axes.set_autoscale_on`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_autoscale_on)

```
ax.axis('auto')
ax.set_autoscale_on()
```

If you want to auto-scale only the x or y axis, you can use `set_autoscaley_on` or `set_autoscalex_on`.

Comment: This is great thanks! I had to use "set_autoscale_on(True)".

Comment: is there a way to autoscale the xticks in a similar way?

Comment: @denvar matplotlib should already automatically create xticks for you unless you hard-coded ticks in some way. That's really part of a separate question, but you would need to post some of the code so we could see what was happening.